# how to create a js prototype class in external file

Tags: javascript

I created an external .js file with prototype:

```
function Logger() {
    var log = new Array("");
}

Logger.prototype.AddLine = function (value) {
    if (value) {
        Logger.log.push("\t" + value);
    }
}

Logger.prototype.ReadLog = function () {
    return this.log.join("");
}
```

And now I try to use it on my page. I included my file in the header. And I have simple js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var log = new Logger();
        log.AddLine("User entered the page");
});
```

Firebug error: 
TypeError: Logger.log is undefined
[Break On This Error]
Logger.log.push("\t" + value);

Can anyone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: did you load your script before calling it?

Comment: Yeah, but it's in document ready so it shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: Can you check your assets if your external script has loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set `log` on the `Logger` instance to an empty array, use `this.log = []`, not `var log`. The latter creates a private variable, which you can't access outside the function.

Also, `Logger.log` means: access the `log` property on the `Logger` function. Here you want the instance instead, so use `this.log` (like you did in `ReadLog`).

Answer (score 3):

You are using four (!) different `log` things:

- `var log = new Logger();` is a (local) variable containing an new `Logger` instance
- `var log = new Array("");` is a (local) variable that is scoped to the constructor function it is declared in. You will not be able to access it from outside
- `Logger.log.…` is a property on the `Logger` *function object*. There is nothing, so this line will throw the error.
- `this.log.…` is what you actually want, a property on the current instance.

So change your script to this:

```
function Logger() {
    this.log = [""]; // not sure why not just an empty array
}

Logger.prototype.AddLine = function (value) {
    if (value) {
        this.log.push("\t" + value);
    }
};

Logger.prototype.readLog = function () {
    return this.log.join("");
};
```